# Integral and derivative

Tags: integration, derivatives

Let $g(x) = \int_{[0;2^x]}{\sin(t^2)} dt$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$. I have to calculate $g'(0)$. So, $g'(0) = \lim_{h \to 0}{\frac{g(h) - \int_{[0;1]}{\sin(t^2)} dt}{h}}$. Maybe I should apply the formula $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)=\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx$, but I don't think it would help. How to end the calculation?

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$ F(x) = \int_{0}^{x}\sin(t^2)\,dt.$$
We have $\frac{d}{dx}F(x)=\sin(x^2)$ by the fundamental theorem of Calculus, and:
$$ g(x) = F(2^x) = F(e^{x\log 2}),$$
so the chain rule gives:
$$ g'(x) = 2^x \log 2 \sin(4^x) $$
and by evaluating the previous line in $x=0$ we have:

> $$ g'(0) = \log 2\cdot \sin 1.$$